# Export Excel Range to Access table VBA

Tags: ms-access

I want to have a button on the Excel spreadsheet and have the data copied to the Access table. 
The range is an auto-populated field from another sheet in the same workbook.

I tried few codes to make this happen, but I either get an error 1004: application-defined or object-defined error, or no error but data not being copied in Access DB.

My code is copied below.

```
Sub Export_Data()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 
    Dim dbPath
    Dim x As Long, i As Long

    dbPath = "H:\RFD\RequestForData.accdb"

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

    rst.Open Source:="tblRequests", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
             CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
             Options:=adCmdTable

    rst.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 13
        rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
    Next i
    rst.Update

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

    MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you import the data from Access rather than Excel ? If so `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` could do what you want, I think

Comment: what is x? it's not initialized anywhere.

Comment: Yes, x is not initialized or incremented. You want to populate 13 fields and only 1 record?

Comment: Yep! one record starting at row 7, with 24 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your Subroutine I see two things that can make it not to work:

- rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value  <- Where is 'x' initialized?
- There is only one loop that moves over the fields but I think it should be another loop for the rows in the Excel.

With this two changes, the loop when the records are save could become something like this:

```
    For x = 1 TO lastRow   ' Last row has to be calculated somehow
        rst.AddNew
        For i = 1 To 13
            rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
        Next i
        rst.Update
    Next x
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have tried your code. I was able to have a message box saying "The data has been successfully sent to the access database" but when I go back to the database, no record is there. Also, since the record in the excel spreadsheet starts at row 7, i have set x=7. @USeptim

Comment: Hi Joanne. I have reproduced a similar example (with only three fields) and it has worked. The rows are added to the Access database. I would make some control tests, for example add a counter that records how many rows has your routine processed and add a messagebox showing that number or check that the primary key field is populated... I would test that kind of things...